# Confused about lifetime of variable

Tags: rust

I'm reading a file:

```
let mut file = BufferedReader::new(File::open(path));
let mut first: bool = true;
for a_line in file.lines() {
    let mut line = a_line.unwrap();
    let line = line.as_slice().trim();
    if first && line != "[shogun]" {
        //let line = a_line.unwrap().as_slice().trim();
        //if first &&  line.trim() != "[shogun]" {
        return None;
    }
    first = false;
}
return Some(Settings { log: String::new() });
```

This works fine. But if I try to inline the creation of `line`:

```
let line = a_line.unwrap().as_slice().trim();
```

I get an odd error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
```

What's so special about inlining these calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a_line.unwrap()` is a `String`. It owns its contents.

`.as_slice()` (and in turn `.trim()`) then takes a reference to that data; it requires that that base value continue to live so that there can be something for it to refer to.

This is what has happened in this case: you have not stored the `String` in a variable and so it will live for the expression only, and so the `&str` which is a reference to that `String` (or its contents) cannot outlive the expression.

Thus what would in C or C++ have been a use-after-free bug (because the `String` is freed at the end of the `let line = …;` line), or might alternatively have been written as a memory leak, if you had omitted the freeing of the `String`, becomes a compilation error.

Comment: In C++ wouldn't the String live within the scope of the loop?

Comment: I’m assuming the `let line = a_line.unwrap().as_slice().trim();` form; I don’t know for certain what C++’s scoping rules are, but I’m presuming them to be similar to Rust’s. I could certainly be wrong on that.

Comment: Same as C and Java. This is inside a loop so the variable should live until the end of the loop.

Comment: But you haven’t assigned it (`a_line.unwrap()`) anywhere.

Comment: Yes I did? Assigned it to `line` then reassigned the value of line.

Comment: And that’s why *that* form of it works. But when you changed that it stopped working.